# Plotting boxplots grouped by color in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Below is my code to plot a box plot in ggplot2.I want to group the box plots by a type,so that all types are grouped together and colored.But I am still getting it mixed up.

```
p=ggplot(brcp.df,aes(variable,value)) + geom_point(shape=1) 
p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=factor(type))) + geom_point(aes(color = factor(type)),outlier.colour="red") +geom_text(aes(label = gene) , size = 4,position = position_jitter(width = 0.6))
```

Do I need to add anything in my code above.For reference,below is my data.

```
 variable gene      value diagnosis     type      lQntl       uQntl     lBound    uBound
1 PM169_Z7 <NA> -0.1220775      CRPC Prostate -0.3693246 -0.02714948 -0.8825873 0.4861132
2 PM169_Z7 <NA> -0.4711975      CRPC Prostate -0.3693246 -0.02714948 -0.8825873 0.4861132
3 PM169_Z7 <NA> -0.5884106      CRPC Prostate -0.3693246 -0.02714948 -0.8825873 0.4861132
```

Thanks

Comment: Try `geom_boxplot(aes(fill=factor(type)),position = position_dodge(width = .8))` and use `position_dodge` for your points, too.

Comment: no,it does not work.

Comment: Yes, it does (in terms of plotting the boxes side by side).

Comment: In my case,its not.I want the boxes of each type side by side.

Comment: I have tried something like  facet_wrap(~ type) and + facet_grid(~ type),but then the variable labels don't occur and since I have 80 variables,they get cluttered when more variables in a single type

Answer (score 1):

As I commented:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(brcp.df,
       aes(x = variable, 
           y = value)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=factor(type)), 
               position = position_dodge(width = .8))
```

produces boxes of each type (here just 2) side by side:

[image]

I used

```
brcp.df <- read.table(header=T, text="
variable gene      value diagnosis     type      lQntl       uQntl     lBound    uBound
1 PM169_Z7 <NA> -0.1220775      CRPC Prostate -0.3693246 -0.02714948 -0.8825873 0.4861132
2 PM169_Z7 <NA> -0.4711975      CRPC Prostate -0.3693246 -0.02714948 -0.8825873 0.4861132
3 PM169_Z7 <NA> -0.5884106      CRPC Prostate -0.3693246 -0.02714948 -0.8825873 0.4861132
4 PM169_Z7 <NA> -0.1220775      CRPC Prostate2 -0.3693246 -0.02714948 -0.8825873 0.4861132
5 PM169_Z7 <NA> -0.4711975      CRPC Prostate2 -0.3693246 -0.02714948 -0.8825873 0.4861132
6 PM169_Z7 <NA> -0.5884106      CRPC Prostate2 -0.3693246 -0.02714948 -0.8825873 0.4861132")
```

Comment: i have multiple variables within the same type.I wanted to post an image to show the error but I don't have the required reputation for that.